# How can Exchange be configured to escalate an email through people until it is read?

Tags: exchange

How can I configure Microsoft Exchange to take an email to a specific common email address and put it in a particular person's inbox and if that person hasn't read the email in 10 minutes, put it in another person's inbox, and then 10 minutes later another's inbox, and to keep doing this until someone has read it.  Then, when someone has read it, mark everyone's email as "read" or somehow mark it as being taken care of at that time?

Comment: You can't.  That's not what Exchange is for.  It's an email platform, not an alerting one.  You might be able to hack together a convoluted way to hammer a nail with an orange, but you should probably grab a hammer instead.  It'll be easier, and spray less pulp and citric acid around.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a proper service management tool. Exchange cannot do it.
The email would be delivered by Exchange to a shared mailbox, the service management tool would then pick up the email and then deal with the escalation process itself. Exchange cannot do it as already pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

[Public Folders](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150538(v=exchg.150).aspx) are about as close to this as you're going to get, but Exchange isn't designed with this use case in mind.